# Battleship game in Java language

Tags: java, arrays

I need some help with my code for my school project. I have done some simple game in Java, it is on 5x5 board, randomly positioned ships.

I am stuck with something that I can't manage alone, I need some brains more to help me with it. I need to make a ship which need to position itself on 2 places on board, so if you are playing against PC you'll need two shots to sink that boat.

Code is below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] board = new int[5][5];
    int[][] ships = new int[3][2];
    int[] shoot = new int[2];
    int attempts=0,
        shotHit=0;
    
    initBoard(board);
    initShips(ships);
    
    System.out.println();
    
    do{
        showBoard(board);
        shoot(shoot);
        attempts++;
        
        if(hit(shoot,ships)){
            hint(shoot,ships,attempts);
            shotHit++;
        }                
        else
            hint(shoot,ships,attempts);
        
        changeboard(shoot,ships,board);
        

    }while(shotHit!=3);
    
    System.out.println("\n\n\nBattleship Java game finished! You hit 3 ships in "+attempts+" attempts");
    showBoard(board);
}

public static void initBoard(int[][] board){
    for(int row=0 ; row < 5 ; row++ )
        for(int column=0 ; column < 5 ; column++ )
            board[row][column]=-1;
}

public static void showBoard(int[][] board){
    System.out.println("\t1 \t2 \t3 \t4 \t5");
    System.out.println();
    
    for(int row=0 ; row < 5 ; row++ ){
        System.out.print((row+1)+"");
        for(int column=0 ; column < 5 ; column++ ){
            if(board[row][column]==-1){
                System.out.print("\t"+"~");
            }else if(board[row][column]==0){
                System.out.print("\t"+"*");
            }else if(board[row][column]==1){
                System.out.print("\t"+"X");
            }
            
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

}

public static void initShips(int[][] ships){
    Random random = new Random();
    
    for(int ship=0 ; ship < 3 ; ship++){
        ships[ship][0]=random.nextInt(5);
        ships[ship][1]=random.nextInt(5);
        
        //let's check if that shot was already tried 
        //if it was, just finish the do...while when a new pair was randomly selected
        for(int last=0 ; last < ship ; last++){
            if( (ships[ship][0] == ships[last][0])&&(ships[ship][1] == ships[last][1]) )
                do{
                    ships[ship][0]=random.nextInt(5);
                    ships[ship][1]=random.nextInt(5);
                }while( (ships[ship][0] == ships[last][0])&&(ships[ship][1] == ships[last][1]) );
        }
        
    }
}

public static void shoot(int[] shoot){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Row: ");
    shoot[0] = input.nextInt();
    shoot[0]--;
    
    System.out.print("Column: ");
    shoot[1] = input.nextInt();
    shoot[1]--;
    
}

public static boolean hit(int[] shoot, int[][] ships){
    
    for(int ship=0 ; ship<ships.length ; ship++){
        if( shoot[0]==ships[ship][0] && shoot[1]==ships[ship][1]){
            System.out.printf("You hit a ship located in (%d,%d)\n",shoot[0]+1,shoot[1]+1);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static void hint(int[] shoot, int[][] ships, int attempt){
    int row=0,
        column=0;
    
    for(int line=0 ; line < ships.length ; line++){
        if(ships[line][0]==shoot[0])
            row++;
        if(ships[line][1]==shoot[1])
            column++;
    }
    
    System.out.printf("\nHint %d: \nRow %d -> %d ships\n" +
                             "Column %d -> %d ships\n",attempt,shoot[0]+1,row,shoot[1]+1,column);
}

public static void changeboard(int[] shoot, int[][] ships, int[][] board){
    if(hit(shoot,ships))
        board[shoot[0]][shoot[1]]=1;
    else
        board[shoot[0]][shoot[1]]=0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SF. Please, specify the concrete problem with your code and ask it as a question.

Comment: Thank you for replying so fast. Well there is nothing wrong with the actual code, i just need some game upgrades. For now I have a game with 5x5 board (text mode) it is not JavaFX stuff, and 3 randomly placed ships on that board where each of the ships take just one place on the board and it takes just one hit to sank the ship. What I need is to make a ship where it will be needed to get two hits on him to get him out of the game. So let's say i have two ships with 1 HP and one ship with 2 HP.

Comment: @DominikFuček I will give you a high level approach to your problem. Once you generate the random position for the ship. Do another random roll to pick one of the 4 adjacent "squares" for the 2nd part of the ship. Beware that you must include checks that another ship is not already there (like the one that you have) or that you are not going out of the array borders in case the 1st position was on one of the border positions. Additionally in case none of the adjacent squares are available, you will need to reroll the whole ship position.

Comment: @Dimitris Well thank you, that helped me a lot, just to get some logic out of it. I am having trouble now with showing that another spot (adjacent field) on the game board when I am printing the board. Can somebody help me with that?

Comment: @DominikFuček I am not sure what you mean by "showing", update your code and ask a question specific on your code.

Comment: @Dimitris By "showing" i mean printing the board for "user". I would like to check if the ships are generating correctly and it is only possible to see the ships with "System.out.print()" :D I'm sorry if my english isn't the strongest but i hope you will understand what I am asking.

Comment: @DominikFuček I am not sure how you save the new position. If for example you save it in position 3 & 4 of the ships array, you will need to include it in the code snippet that I provided to you.

Comment: @DominikFuček some generic remarks. Java is an OOP language, use it to your advantage. It would make your life much easier if you had a class for the ship and maybe even for the board. Also java provides ways to generate basic graphics to fulfil your needs. Check out GridLayout https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html.

Comment: @Dimitris Well thank you bro, that is super nice. I know that this is OOP language, just now I am working on a new way of making this game, with same board but with "Ship" objects, and i already made "Ship" class for now. 
This is very helpful because my logic can be a little rusty from time to time, and i needed some opinion with this stuff. Thank you very much, if you come in Zagreb, you'll get a beer.

Comment: @DominikFuček Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Following your partner of design.

```
   public static void showShips(int[][] ships)
    {
        for (int ship = 0; ship < ships[0].length; ship++) {
            System.out.println("Ship: " + (ship + 1));
            System.out.println("Position 1: (" + (ships[ship][0]+1) + "," + (ships[ship][1]+1) + ")");
    }

    System.out.println("\t1 \t2 \t3 \t4 \t5");
    System.out.println();

    for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
        System.out.print((row + 1) + "");
        for (int column = 0; column < 5; column++) {
            boolean flag = false;
            for (int ship = 0; ship < ships[0].length; ship++) {
                if (row == ships[ship][0] && column == ships[ship][1]) {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            if (flag) {
                System.out.print("\t" + "x");
            } else {
                System.out.print("\t" + "~");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few comments first.

Your method `initShips` is wrong: if the coordinates you randomly generated match those of a previously placed ship, you will generate new coordinates, but will only test against one ship.

It should be something like this:

```
public static void initShips(int[][] ships) {
    Random random = new Random();

    for (int ship = 0; ship < 3; ship++) {
        do {
            ships[ship][0] = random.nextInt(5);
            ships[ship][1] = random.nextInt(5);
        } while (hitsPreviousShip(ships, ship));
    }
}

private static boolean hitsPreviousShip(int[][] ships, int ship) {
    for (int last = 0; last < ship; last++) {
        if ((ships[ship][0] == ships[last][0]) && (ships[ship][1] == ships[last][1])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now I would take a different approach to model the game:

In each cell of the board, I would store one of the following values:

- -1 if the cell is empty (you already have that)
- -2 if the cell is part of a ship that was hit
- 0 to 4 the index of the ship that occupies the cell

That way, you don't need to memorize the coordinates of the ships, and it's easier to test the status of a cell.

Now, for a single-cell ship, you generate randomly a row number and a column number, for a multi-cell ship, you would additionally generate a direction (0 = horizontal or 1 = vertical). You would not only have to check that the new ship is not intersecting with an already placed ship, you would have to check that no cell of the ship is out of the board.

You would still need an array with a single integer for each ship; it would represent the number of cells the ship occupies not yet hit, meaning that if it is 0, the ship is sunk.

The initialization would be slightly different. To place two single-cell ships and one double-cell ship, you would do something like this:

```
public static void initShips(int[][] board, int[] ships) {
    Random random = new Random();

    initShip(random, board, ships, 0, 1);
    initShip(random, board, ships, 1, 1);
    initShip(random, board, ships, 2, 2);
}

private static void initShip(Random random, int[][] board, int[] ships, int ship, int length) {
    int row, col, dir;
    do {
        dir = random.nextInt(2);
        if (dir == 0) { // horizontal
            row = random.nextInt(5);
            col = random.nextInt(6-length);
        } else { // vertical
            row = random.nextInt(5);
            col = random.nextInt(6-length);
        }
    } while (hitsPreviousShip(board, row, col, dir, length));
    ships[ship] = length;
    if (dir == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            board[row][col+i] = ship;
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            board[row+i][col] = ship;
        }
    }
}

private static boolean hitsPreviousShip(int[][] board, int row, int col, int dir, int length) {
    if (dir == 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            if (board[row][col+i] >= 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            if (board[row+i][col] >= 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```